# Route parameter in first place always re-mounts component - React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use React Router in a way where the route parameter is the first thing in the route path, like so (see 'siteId' param)

```
<Route path={"/:siteId/calendar/:calendarId?" component={Calendar} />
<Route path={"/:siteId/client/:clientId?" component={Calendar} />
...
```

The problem I'm facing is that React Router will remount (unmount+mount) the component every time I redirect the user (using history.push), even though the new path goes through the exact same `<Route>` component.

For example, being on the path `/someSiteId/calendar/someCalendarId` and calling `history.push("someOtherSiteId/calendar/someOtherCalendarId")` will resolve in the same `<Route>` as I'm currently in being rendered, but instead of just re-rendering this already mounted component, it will re-mount it.

As far as I could test, I figured out this behaviour happens due to the dynamic parameter at the beginning of the route path. If using static, everything works fine.

Are there any known workarounds to be able to have a route parameter at the first place in the path without remounting components?

Comment: If it is re-mounting, it is due to code that you aren't showing yet in your question. You can click the links in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww5v37xz2k) to see that it does not re-mount (initialSiteId is successfully remembered).

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it seems you are right, I'll dig around the code more.